# Windows hard restart

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible to "hard" restart Windows, without waiting for closing applications, etc.?

Comment: Pressing the power-button or unplugging the power cord should have this result.

Comment: Open a command window and type `shutdown /?` .  Also: that's not the definition of "hard restart."

Comment: @Patrick: Your solution will not work if he is using a notebook with battery :D

Comment: @danny: removing the battery will ;-)

Comment: Hold down the power button for 6 seconds.  Bang, that's a hard one.

Answer (score 5):

At the command prompt:

```
SHUTDOWN -r -t 01
```

Comment: If it's elevated you can run shutdown.exe /f /r /t 0

Comment: +1 The first idea of mine. However this command will also wait for closing applications :(

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself why Windows waits for the programs to close.

Comment: The /f parameter forcefully closes the applications, but it does not sound like a safe idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8a8bbd4b-9a80-4785-afc7-1e8e6daa3d42. Call ExitWindowsEx with EWX_REBOOT and EWX_FORCEIFHUNG.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `SHUTDOWN` tool command, to eliminate completely the waiting time for closing applications, under
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`, set `WaitToKillAppTimeout` value to `0`, and set `AutoEndTasks` value to `1`,

[WaitToKillAppTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978624.aspx) value determines how long the system waits for user processes to end after the user attempts to log off or to shut down Windows. When the time specified in this entry expires, the End Task dialog box appears, stating that the process did not respond. If the value of `AutoEndTasks` is `1`, the system ends the process automatically.

The trick here is to manipulate the registry value-data of both value-names before calling `ExitWindowsEx()`, and schedule a task that will restore the value-names to their original value-data on the next restart of Windows.